# Issue with saving data in the 'name' column of the 'videos' table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-8, store

Problem: Despite successful video uploads, the 'name' column in the 'videos' table of my Laravel application remains null. I'm using the following code to upload videos and store their names in the 'name' column

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|min:3',
            'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
            'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
            'pseudo' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'birthday' => 'nullable|date',
            'birthday_place' => 'nullable',
            'death' => 'nullable|date',
            'family_status' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'date_joining' => 'nullable|date',
            'zone' => 'nullable',
            'side' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'division' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'responsibility' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'resume' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'keys' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'hash' => 'nullable',
            'type' => 'nullable',
            'indexinfg_aid' => 'nullable',
            'notice' => 'nullable',

            'pays' =>'nullable',
            'emplois' =>'nullable',

            'recorde_date' =>'nullable|date',
            'recorde_place' =>'nullable',
            'time' =>'nullable',
            'animator' =>'nullable',
            'localisation' =>'nullable',
            'links' =>'nullable',

            
            
        ]);
        $request->merge(['user_id' => auth()->user()->id]);
        $temoignage =  Temoignage::create($request->all());
       // table video
        $data= new Video();
        $data->temoignage_id=$temoignage->id;
        $data->recorde_date=$request->recorde_date;
        $data->recorde_place=$request->recorde_place;
        $data->time=$request->time;
        $data->animator=$request->animator;
        $data->localisation=$request->localisation;
        $data->links=$request->links;

        if ($request->video != null) {
            $cleanedFileName = basename($request->video); // Nettoyez le nom du fichier
            $sourceFilePath = public_path('folder/tmp/video/' . $cleanedFileName);
            $destinationFilePath = public_path('folder/video/' . $cleanedFileName);
            
            if (file_exists($sourceFilePath)) {
                File::copy($sourceFilePath, $destinationFilePath);
                $data->name = $cleanedFileName;
            } else {
                // Gérer le cas où le fichier source n'existe pas
                // Peut-être une redirection ou un message d'erreur approprié
            }

            if ($request->hasFile('video')) {
                $videoFile = $request->file('video');
                $videoFileName = 'mojahidine' . time() . '.' . $videoFile->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $videoFile->move(public_path('folder/video/'), $videoFileName);
                $video->name = $videoFileName;
            }
        }

        $data->save();
        // table photo
        if($photos = $request->file("photo"))
        {
            $count=1;
            foreach($photos as $imagefile){
              $string=uniqid();
              $img= new Photo;
              
              $fileName =  'mojahidine'.time().$string.'.'.$imagefile->getClientOriginalExtension();  
              $imagefile->move(public_path('folder/photo'), $fileName);
    
             $img->name = $fileName;
             $img->temoignage_id = $temoignage->id;
            
             $img->save();
             $count++;
           }
        }
        // table docs 
        if($docs = $request->file("docs"))
        {
            $count=1;
            foreach($docs as $imagefile){
              $string=uniqid();
              $img= new Doc;
              
              $fileName =  'mojahidine'.time().$string.'.'.$imagefile->getClientOriginalExtension();  
              $imagefile->move(public_path('folder/docs'), $fileName);
    
             $img->name = $fileName;
             $img->temoignage_id = $temoignage->id;
            
             $img->save();
             $count++;
           }
        }


        return redirect()->route('temoignage.index')->with('success','تم إنشاء الشهادة  بنجاح');
    }
```

Despite this, the 'name' column remains null. Videos are successfully uploaded to the 'public/folder/tmp/video/' directory. What could be causing the 'name' column to stay null despite the upload?"

here is my model Video.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Video extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'recorde_date',
        'recorde_place',
        'time',
        'animator',
        'localisation',
        'links',
        'download',
        'clicks',
        'view',
        'status',
        'temoignage_id'
       
    ];
}
```

and Temoignage.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Temoignage extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'pseudo',
        'birthday',
        'birthday_place',
        'death',
        'family_status',
        'country',
        'type',
        'date_joining',
        'zone',
        'side',
        'division',
        'responsibility',
        'resume',
        'keys',
        'hash',
        'indexinfg_aid',
        'notice',
        'wilaya_id',
        'etablisement_id',
        'job_id',
        'section_id',
        'user_id',
        'pays',
        'emplois'

    ];

    public function wilayas(){
        
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\wilaya','wilaya_id');
    }
    // public function videos(){
        
    //     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Video');
    // }
    public function videos(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Video','id','temoignage_id');
    }
    public function scopeSearch($query, $filter)
    {
        return $query->where(function($query) use ($filter) {
            $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')
                  ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')
                  ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%');
        });
    }

    public function section()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Section::class);
    }
    public function etablisements()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Etablisement::class,'etablisement_id');
    }

    

   
    
    
}
```

I attempted to upload videos using Laravel, expecting the 'name' column in the 'videos' table to be populated with the uploaded file names. However, despite successful uploads, the 'name' column remains null in the database. I expected the 'name' column to store the video file names, but this did not happen

I tried several codes by searching on google or chatgpt but it didn't work

Comment: That all being said, you're doing `$data = new Video();`, but then `$video->name = $videoFileName;`. Where is `$video` defined? That should probably be `$data->name = $videoFileName;`, then `$data->save()` will correctly populate `name` in your database. Or maybe you should be doing `$video = new Video();`, but either way, you need to define and reference the correct variable names.